# Boiling potatoes

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, water, food

1. If the temperature of boiling water is about 100 ºC (depending on air pressure), why are boiled potatoes on a high stove flame cooked faster?
2. From the [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylamide#Discovery_of_acrylamide_in_foods):

> Acrylamide was discovered in foods in April 2002 by Eritrean scientist
>   Eden Tareke in Sweden when she found the chemical in starchy foods,
>   such as potato chips (potato crisps), French fries (chips), and bread
>   that had been heated **higher than 120 °C** (248 °F) (production of
>   acrylamide in the heating process was shown to be
>   temperature-dependent). It was not found in food that had been boiled
>   or in foods that were not heated.

If I boil potatoes on the highest stove flame, will the potatoes not reach the temperature of 120 ºC?

Comment: Are you asking how fire (from a stove) can be hotter than boiling water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether your stove is on 'high' or 'low' doesn't change the temperature of the water, i.e. the boiling point remains $100\ \mathrm{C}$. So the potatoes can **NEVER** reach $120\ \mathrm{C}$.

But objects being heated by hot water follow [Newton's Law of Cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law) (and Heating), which describes the *heat transfer* per unit of time, $\frac{dQ}{dt}$:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=hA[T_{BP}-T_{pot}(t)]$$

We can derive from this, for potatoes plunged into boiling hot water at $t=0$, with $T_0$ their ambient (and initial) temperature and $T_e$ their end temperature, their temperature evolution in time $t$:

$$T_e=T_{BP}-(T_{BP}-T_0)e^{-\frac{hA}{mc_p}t}$$

And the heating time:

$$t=\frac{mc_p}{hA}\times \ln\Big({\frac{T_{BP}-T_0}{T_{BP}-T_e}}\Big)$$

($m$ is mass of potatoes, $c_p$ their specific heat capacity and $A$ their surface area)

The factor $h$ is the *heat transfer coefficient* (in $\mathrm{Wm^{-2}K}$). **It is obvious that when $h$ goes up, $t$ goes down.**

In fluids, like water, $h$ is known to be somewhat dependent on the [Reynolds Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number), which is higher in turbulent conditions. More turbulent conditions *favour* higher heat transfer rates.

For that reason there may be a *slight* increase in heat transfer (and thus a slight reduction in cooking time) when comparing a vigorous boil (high heat) to a gentle simmer (low heat).

Comment: What about cooking devices that put the water under pressure? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_cooking

Comment: Pressure cookers elevate the BP by a 10 or 15 C. I doubt if any could reach 120 C.

Comment: @Gert in a stable system (continuous boiling) isn't the temperature of both the potatoes and the water constant and equal, i.e. dQ/dt=0. If so, how does h (heat transfer coefficient) matter? Also could you provide an intuitive explanation of this phenomenon, beyond the equations (which are a mathematical representation of some attributes of the actual system)

Comment: @rapt: well, no. The potatoes start at ambient temperature and then slowly heat up till $100\ \mathrm{C}$. So $h$ matters GREATLY in heating/cooling processes. What Newton says is that the heating *rate* is proportional to the difference $T_{BP}-T_{pot}$ (in this case). I find that quite intuitive because heating is about *transferring kinetic energy* from the 'hot molecules' to the 'cold molecules'. Temperature is a measure of the average kinetic energy of the particles that make up an object.

Comment: @Gert I do not know how long it takes for the potatoes to reach 100 ºC. But are you saying that (1) I can accelerate the heating of the potatoes themselves up to 100 ºC by starting the cooking with the highest flame and (2) once the potatoes reach the water temperature (100 ºC), I can lower the flame (as long as it's high enough to keep the whole mass of water boiling), save energy, and still have the potatoes cooked at the minimum total time? This is not exactly what I experience when cooking beans - constant high flame significantly reduces the total cooking time. Could you explain?

Comment: Yes to both! But the effect on cooking time will be quite small. Beans are viscous, the effect of higher heat on $h$ is definitely more marked. Constant stirring really helps as well (beans).

Comment: @Gert what I find not intuitive is how turbulence accelerates the heating of the potatoes (other than it helps in distributing the 100 ºC water from the bottom of the pot evenly to other areas of the pot). I don't see in Reynolds equation a direct reference to temperature. Can I achieve the same or even faster rate of cooking by artificially creating turbulence in the water (fans to circulate the water, and/or adding air bubbles), instead of wasting energy on higher heat? P.S. I think you want to make it Tbp(t) instead of Tpot(t), if we assume we start the experiment from a boiling pot.

Comment: In  these problems of *convection* heating, the potato is surrounded by a convection layer that acts more or less as an insulator. At higher turbulence (higher $Re$) that layer becomes slimmer and thus less insulting. Higher $Re$ thus gives rise to higher $h$. See e.g. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=heat+convection+coefficient+reynolds&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXn9Xzo-zXAhVJB8AKHYVoDhwQsAQIaw&biw=1175&bih=525#imgrc=6LmSnwTvBg55xM: in the graph, $U$ is our $h$, just different notation.

Comment: @Gert Oh interesting, an insulation layer. So according to what you say, if nobody already did it, it might be worthwhile inventing a pot with a fan / artificial turbulence, to save energy. There was just one issue that I did not understand - why are beans so much affected by constant high flame? I understand why their viscosity requires hotter pot bottom to create turbulence, but due to their small size, shortly after the water boil, the beans reach 100 ºC. So the rate of heat transfer is now about 0? Why then the turbulence still has an effect at this point (the equation says it won't).

Comment: There's still heat transfer with the beans boiling as the flame is much hotter than the boiling beans. It's different from the potatoes because you're not just heating the beans, you're heating the sauce too. Made an edit for heating time.